# Deleted dags appear in dags list and db

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to delete a dag named 'twitterQueryParse' which you can see in this screenshot from my dags list:

```
airflow dags list
```

[image]
I've executed:

```
airflow dags delete twitterQueryParse
```

So I'm getting the anticipated error message:

```
[2022-12-25 09:39:49,657] {__init__.py:42} INFO - Loaded API auth backend: airflow.api.auth.backend.session
This will drop all existing records related to the specified DAG. Proceed? (y/n)y
[2022-12-25 09:39:53,555] {delete_dag.py:46} INFO - Deleting DAG: twitterQueryParse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 103, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py", line 163, in dag_delete
    message = api_client.delete_dag(dag_id=args.dag_id)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 38, in delete_dag
    count = delete_dag.delete_dag(dag_id)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rony/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/api/common/delete_dag.py", line 57, in delete_dag
    raise DagNotFound(f"Dag id {dag_id} not found")
airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id twitterQueryParse not found
```

But when I list the dags again twitterQueryParse remains on the list, even following a reset and initialization of the airflow db:

```
airflow db reset
airflow db init
```

My airflow version is 2.4.2
How do I delete this dag completely from the airflow system?

Comment: The exception is raised on the dags table, did you check if the dag has some records on the other tables (runs, tasks)? maybe you need to clean the db manually

Comment: Thanks Hussein, I'll check, but how do I clean the db manually?